# Laravel 4 adds "1" at the end of include file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

There is something I really couldn't understand, why is my Laravel adds a "1" at the end of the include file?

Main file:

```
<?php include app_path()."/views/include.php"; ?>
```

Include file:

```
<?php echo "some text"; ?>
```

It end out with

```
some text1
```

Do you have any idea why an extra "1" there? No matter how I test, it always adds an "1" there.

Comment: Somewhere, probably in other code, you are echoing the result of a boolean function call. it returns true, which is cast as a 1 when output to the screen. It isn't this code, but it is some code somewhere else.

Comment: Unless you are actually doing `echo include ....`, which would cause the exact output you see on successful inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are using `echo include` if your code is as clean as you show here.

Answer (score 1):

You have that `1` in any other view, layout or subview on your app. It happened many times to me, several of them I went in to the Laravel source code just to find that it was in my code. Search hard for it.